# how to add jquery fadein in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function inside_out(folder){
    var typebox = document.getElementById("typebox");
    var Loader = document.getElementById("thumbnail_loader");
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("POST", "json_type_data.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var d = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            typebox.innerHTML = "";
            for(var o in d){
                if(d[o].src){
                    //create image
                    typebox.innerHTML += "<div class='typebox'><img id='typeImg' width='30px' height='30px' src="+d[o].src+"></div>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    hr.send("folder="+folder);
}
```

sorry i have done research but i still have no idea how to add fadein in my innerHTML , can any one give me a clue please, my intetion was when the xml finish loading , those image will fadein.

i tryed jquery fadein but i can get it work , i am using jquery 1.9.1

Comment: put `$('#typebox').fadeIn()` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function inside_out(folder) {
  var typebox = document.getElementById("typebox");
  var typeboxJQS = $('#typebox');
  var Loader = document.getElementById("thumbnail_loader");
  var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  hr.open("POST", "json_type_data.php", true);
  hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
      var d = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
      typebox.innerHTML = "";
      var temp = '';
      typeboxJQS.fadeOut();
      for (var o in d) {
        if (d.hasOwnProperty(o) && d[o].hasOwnProperty('src') && d[o].src !== '') {
          temp += "<div class='typebox'><img id='typeImg' width='30px' height='30px' src=" + d[o].src + "></div>";
        }
      }
      typebox.innerHTML = temp;
      typeboxJQS.fadeIn();
    }
  };
  hr.send("folder=" + folder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to suggest refactoring working code. However if you're going to use jQuery to do something simple like a fade in. Why not use jQuery to make all the harder stuff easier?

```
function inside_out(folder) {
  var typeboxJQS = $('#typebox');
  var Loader = $("#thumbnail_loader");
  $.ajax({
        url: "json_type_data.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: "folder=" + folder,
        success: function(d){
            var temp = '';
            typeboxJQS.html('').fadeOut();
            for (var o in d) {
                 if (d.hasOwnProperty(o) && d[o].hasOwnProperty('src') && d[o].src !== '') {
                     temp += "<div class='typebox'><img id='typeImg' width='30px' height='30px' src=" + d[o].src + "></div>";
                 }
            }
            typeboxJQS.html(temp).fadeIn();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            console.log("textStatus = " + textStatus + "\terrorThrown = " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```